# replace null values using a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'category': [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2], 'cost': [33, 33, 18, np.nan, 8, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

 category cost
0   1   33.0
1   1   33.0
2   2   18.0
3   1   NaN
4   3   8.0
5   2   NaN
```

I would like to replace NaN's in the cost column based on the medians grouped by category (`df[['cost', 'category']].groupby(['category']).median()`). So in the example the first NaN (line 3) would be replaced with 33 and second (line 5) would be replaced by 18.

So do something like this:

```
df['field'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_median(row), axis=1)
```

But only for nan values

Comment: @RockyLi I want to replace cost with it's category median, not with median across all categories

Comment: my bad, didn't see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach.

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, df.groupby("category").transform("median"))
```

You can pass a `Series` as a second argument to `replace`. Using `groupby + transform`, we can make sure that group medians are aligned with the respective group rows.

```
   category  cost
0         1  33.0
1         1  33.0
2         2  18.0
3         1  33.0
4         3   8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Preamble.

```
df.set_index('category', inplace=True)
```

The purpose of proposing multiple methods and timing them is purely educational. Timings here are indicative but should not be used as the sole basis of choosing your method, make sure to test with your own data as well.

---

#### `Series.update`

```
df.cost.update(df.groupby('category').cost.median())
df

          cost
category      
1         33.0
1         33.0
2         18.0
1         33.0
3          8.0
```

---

#### `Series.combine_first`

```
df['cost'] = (
   df.cost.combine_first(df.groupby('category').cost.median()))
df

          cost
category      
1         33.0
1         33.0
2         18.0
1         33.0
3          8.0
```

---

#### Tests

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100000)
b = np.random.choice((1, 2, 3, np.nan), 100000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': a, 'cost': b})

%%timeit 
(df.groupby('category')
   .apply(lambda x: x.cost.fillna(x.cost.median()))
   .reset_index(level=0))

%%timeit
df2 = df.set_index('category')
df2.cost.update(df.groupby('category').cost.median())
df2.reset_index()

%%timeit
df2 = df.set_index('category')
df2['cost'] = (
   df.cost.combine_first(df.groupby('category').cost.median()))
df2.reset_index()

664 ms ± 24.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
10 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
17.1 ms ± 305 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible approach -

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]:
   category  cost
0         1  33.0
1         1  33.0
2         2  18.0
3         1   NaN
4         3   8.0
5         2   NaN

In [83]: df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x: x.cost.fillna(x.cost.median())).reset_index(level=0)
Out[83]:
   category  cost
0         1  33.0
1         1  33.0
3         1  33.0
2         2  18.0
5         2  18.0
4         3   8.0
```